# problem with org-impress export

Tags: org-mode

I want to use https://github.com/kinjo/org-impress-js.el with emacs-25.1 and the last org-mode.

Here my configuration:

```el
 (eval-after-load "org"
    '(progn
       (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-impress-js.el")
       (require 'ox-impress-js)))
```

When I want to export (C-c C-e j j) I got the message:

> org-impress-js-section: Symbol’s function definition is void:
>   org-export-get-headline-id

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

The [issue 17](https://github.com/kinjo/org-impress-js.el/issues/17) is related to the problem, however it is still open. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to solve this =/